# How can I find the index of rows that contain a vector of values in any order in an r data.table?

Tags: r, data.table, subset

I have a vector x:

```
x = c(3, 5, 6)
```

And a data.table:

```
data = data.table(a = 1:5, b = c(5, 9, 6, 2, 3), c = c(6, 4, 5, 3, 6), d = 5:10)
```

I would like to filter out all rows of the data that don't contain all three values in x in any order. In this case data would be subsetted to only include rows 3 and 5.

Thanks.

Comment: you don't show any effort to solve the problem - what have you tried?

Comment: So I know if I just want to find rows in which an element of x is found in a particular column:

**data[a %in% x]**

Or if I wanted to find x in a particular order of columns

**data[a == x[1] & b == x[2] & c == x[3]]**

Or if any of x is in a range of particular columns

**data[b == x[2] | c == x[3]]**

But my particular query I do not know how to solve

Answer (score 3):

```
library(gtools)

setkey(data, a, b, c)

data[as.data.table(permutations(3, 3, x)), nomatch = 0]
#   a b c d
#1: 3 6 5 7
#2: 5 3 6 9
```